# ufunc memory consumption in arithemtic expressions

Tags: python, numpy, copy, numpy-ufunc

What is the memory consumption for arithmetic numpy expressions I.e.

```
vec ** 3 + vec ** 2 + vec
```

(vec being a numpy.ndarray). Is an array stored for each intermediate operation? Could such compound expressions have  multiple times the memory  than the underlying ndarray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, a new array will be allocated for each intermediate result. Fortunately, the package `numexpr` is designed to deal with this issue. From the description:

> The main reason why NumExpr achieves better performance than NumPy is that it avoids allocating memory for intermediate results. This results in better cache utilization and reduces memory access in general. Due to this, NumExpr works best with large arrays.

Example:

```
In [97]: xs = np.random.rand(1_000_000)

In [98]: %timeit xs ** 3 + xs ** 2 + xs
26.8 ms ± 371 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [99]: %timeit numexpr.evaluate('xs ** 3 + xs ** 2 + xs')
1.43 ms ± 20.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Thanks to @max9111 for pointing out that numexpr simplifies power to multiplication. It seems that most of the discrepancy in the benchmark is explained by optimization of `xs ** 3`.

```
In [421]: %timeit xs * xs
1.62 ms ± 12 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [422]: %timeit xs ** 2
1.63 ms ± 10.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [423]: %timeit xs ** 3
22.8 ms ± 283 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [424]: %timeit xs * xs * xs
2.52 ms ± 58.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: In this case numexpr also simplifies the power to multiplications. As a rule of thumb a double**uint takes approx. 40-60 times longer than a multiplication.